# Set non-common BaudRate, MATLAB 2017 & termios.h

Tags: c, linux, matlab, serial-port, baud-rate

My os is Ubuntu 16.04 & MATLAB R2017a.

When I'm trying to listen serial port with non-common baud rate, I get error:

```
s = serial('/dev/ttyUSB0','BaudRate',4000001) 
f=open(s);

Open failed: BaudRate could not be set to the specified value.
```

I found, that there is termios.h file with baud-rate definitions, like that

```
#define  B3500000 0010016
#define  B4000000 0010017
```

And if I set baud rate which is not defined I get error.

So, to listen it via terminal at non-common speed, I'm using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <asm/termios.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("%s device speed\n\nSet speed for a serial device.\nFor instance:\n    %s /dev/ttyUSB0 75000\n", argv[0], argv[0]);                   
        return -1;
    }

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    int speed = atoi(argv[2]);

    struct termios2 tio;
    ioctl(fd, TCGETS2, &tio);
    tio.c_cflag &= ~CBAUD;
    tio.c_cflag |= BOTHER;
    tio.c_ispeed = speed;
    tio.c_ospeed = speed;
    int r = ioctl(fd, TCSETS2, &tio);
    close(fd);

    if (r == 0) {
        printf("Changed successfully.\n");
    } else {
        perror("ioctl");
    }
}
```

And after that I'm able to listen the serial port on the non-common serial speed.

Then I come back to the Matlab, and try set the baud-rate which works fine in the terminal. And I'm still getting same error, even more, after creating the serial object, all settings are lost, and it is getting not working in the terminal.

I think Matlab is using some compiled library, which is based on the termios.h, so is it needed to be recompiled.
Am I wrong? Is it possible to solve this issue?

There is another approach - make C program for serial port and then use MEX, to connect it with matlab, looks more unnatural.

Comment: Matlab probably only allows those rates that it has been tested at.  Others may work, but you can't test them all, so test the common ones and block off the rest.

Comment: I need baud-rate 6Mbit/sec

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the maximum baud rate in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962291/whats-the-maximum-baud-rate-in-matlab)

Comment: @CrisLuengo, this is not a duplicate. Also, the answer at that other question is wrong, as it misses the (un)nicety that at least in some circumstances Matlab seems not to allow baud rates which are, in fact, supported by the OS.

Comment: @kenn Then please write a correct answer. And if something is not described in the documentation, make sure to submit a bug report. Each doc page online requests a star rating, you can give a low score and leave a comment about what is missing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'd love if I could write the answer, but I haven't got it. Indeed, I found this page precisely because I have the same problem (except that I'm now on release 2023b).